# Crear un web service con java que retorne una consulta de bd en json

Tags: java, json, webservice

quería saber si me pueden explicar o pasar algún vídeo o página que explique como crear un web service con java donde yo le tenga que pasar un string y dado ese string vaya a la bd a buscar un registro y me retorne los datos de ese registro en formato json.
Ya estuve buscando pero no encontré mucho, soy nuevo con esto de web services.
Gracias!!

Comment: Hola. En su formato actual, tu pregunta no tendria una respuesta correcta acorde a los estandares del sitio. visita [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si necesitas mas ayuda sobre como preguntar o que tipo de preguntas son validas en el sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola de acuerdo a tu pregunta lo que buscas es orientación acerca de servicios web en Java utilizando RESTFUL, existen muchos Frameworks que hacen posible lo que comentas, sin embargo es necesario conocer las bases, te recomiendo utilizar Spring, un framework muy bueno y que hace lo que necesitas.

En el siguiente enlace viene un tutorial de como obtener un JSON a partir de una petición, asumiendo que conoces el lenguaje de JAVA, una vez que realices el ejemplo podras crear tu propio servicio web utilizando tu base de datos.

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Gracias! voy a seguir la guía.

Comment: Si, te dejo un enlace de video que puedes consultar, aquí puedes visualizar el mismo ejemplo utilizando Eclipse:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tVizH8_jY4

Saludos!